# ERROR WP-rocket cache plugin (wordpress) with IIS 10 shows blank page

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, iis, windows-server

I have installed the cache plugin WP-ROCKET in my IIS 10, and suddenly my site broke showing the blank page. (This occurs when the plugin is enbaled and the cache is enabled).

I contacted the plugin support and they have not managed to solve anything, has anyone had the same problem?

They said me, to activate the debug mode, but my site didn't show any error message that colud help us.

PS. I have installed the plugin in other webs on apache in linux and it's works perfectly.

Thanks,

Regards.